# Do you have to leave geth --rpc running forever or once it's synced you stop it?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

if are supposed to stop it at some point, what is correct way and when do you need to run it again?

thanks

Comment: It has to remain running as long as you want to keep your local node in sync.l

Answer (score 0):

If you close once synced it will stop to. ;)